# How to extract certain values from a complex data structure with Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-re

I am trying to extract data from a complex data structure (example will follow). I am not sure what is the best method (e.g. Beautifullsoup) to parse the test and get the desired field in a table. I need for example the number, date and e-mail of each block:

```
var gIg35809469970000987890data = {
  "values": [
    [
      "33765",
      "33765",
      "06-03-2023",
      "John.doe@foo.com",
      "indoor 1",
      "",
      "1",
      "10",
      "16",
      "",
      "DELETE",
      "33765",
      {
        "salt": "abSaocf8wyyJVMYVCEyAlg",
        "protected": "/54hAxJ90PKjrfjGC3Y_a6vaKuq6wF2a3LCPRBN-RlVRZxzepbuNLBRmI2MPaiYoOPPI0miY-MTodCl2rrwBwAg",
        "rowVersion": "vCwg8r2ZJr9wjvHwoZVrvxkfaCrWiTnUcosn89iFOO2yV-UvFxc1oo9AWsJomlw1IpKd-IZTUHLJjefknOMc5g",
        "fields": {
          "DEL": {
            "url": "javascript:void(null);"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    [
      "33623",
      "33623",
      "03-03-2023",
      "John.Doe@foo.com",
      "indoor 1",
      "",
      "1",
      "10",
      "16",
      "",
      "DELETE",
      "33623",
      {
        "salt": "KHpHaz4-fwN4l3fLmPX6AQ",
        "protected": "/B-ZmlAlvRzPee4kU-QvteJQUy0aP89g08BkpdE5CE-i8_JcsN2sKLELqYh2ZZ9vWZTbp4DtWFYjfO5NDAoKsmA",
        "rowVersion": "3JRQAE4fTETSgERkg3kRCuW2nZiUL_jOcSvLGXNkV6-lpfLOLPhduXAlmgcqEI6gSWX-yI-Fd5uMBbU5iqFXZA",
        "fields": {
          "DEL": {
            "url": "javascript:void(null);"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

(Shortened the file)

I was thinking BeautifullSoup + Regex, but not sure.

Also I am not sure what is the data type: dictionary + array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a JSON. which is notable at the objects because the key of the objects are strings not variables. Just parse it into a normal list and then use a for-loop

Comment: Do you consistently want the second, third, and fourth element of those lists?

Comment: @JonSG looks like a job for [**`operator.itemgetter`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

Comment: @JonSG yes I want to extract consistently  those values

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided information there are many options. I'll demonstrate python native package `json` :

```py
import json
str_data = gIg35809469970000987890data # variable name from question. 
obj_data = json.loads(str_data)
# data is loaded into a dict
print(obj_data['values'][0][0]) # returns 33765
print(obj_data['values'][12]['salt']) # returns abSaocf8wyyJVMYVCEyAlg
# it's a popo so you can
obj_data['values'][12]['salt'] = 'abced8dbt6' 
# when finished convert back to json:
str_result = json.dumps(obj_data)
```

[Explanation of json notation](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)
Braces surround dictionaries; square brackets surround lists (just like in python.

Answer (score 0):

The data looks like a json text return from an api

given:

```
data_text = """
{
  "values": [
    [
      "33765",
      "33765",
      "06-03-2023",
      "John.doe@foo.com",
      "indoor 1",
      "",
      "1",
      "10",
      "16",
      "",
      "DELETE",
      "33765",
      {
        "salt": "abSaocf8wyyJVMYVCEyAlg",
        "protected": "/54hAxJ90PKjrfjGC3Y_a6vaKuq6wF2a3LCPRBN-RlVRZxzepbuNLBRmI2MPaiYoOPPI0miY-MTodCl2rrwBwAg",
        "rowVersion": "vCwg8r2ZJr9wjvHwoZVrvxkfaCrWiTnUcosn89iFOO2yV-UvFxc1oo9AWsJomlw1IpKd-IZTUHLJjefknOMc5g",
        "fields": {
          "DEL": {
            "url": "javascript:void(null);"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    [
      "33623",
      "33623",
      "03-03-2023",
      "John.Doe@foo.com",
      "indoor 1",
      "",
      "1",
      "10",
      "16",
      "",
      "DELETE",
      "33623",
      {
        "salt": "KHpHaz4-fwN4l3fLmPX6AQ",
        "protected": "/B-ZmlAlvRzPee4kU-QvteJQUy0aP89g08BkpdE5CE-i8_JcsN2sKLELqYh2ZZ9vWZTbp4DtWFYjfO5NDAoKsmA",
        "rowVersion": "3JRQAE4fTETSgERkg3kRCuW2nZiUL_jOcSvLGXNkV6-lpfLOLPhduXAlmgcqEI6gSWX-yI-Fd5uMBbU5iqFXZA",
        "fields": {
          "DEL": {
            "url": "javascript:void(null);"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
"""
data = json.loads(data_text)
```

You can probably load it directly into a dataframe using:

```py
import pandas
print(pandas.DataFrame(data["values"]))
```

You might also work with it to get the filtered columns more manumatically via:

```py
import json
import pandas

data_dict = [
    row[1:4]
    for row in
    data 
]
print(data_dict)
```

and then to a dataframe if you wished

```py
df = pandas.DataFrame(data_dict)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, in an ugly way, but will try Pandas as well. Makes more sense as well, as I want to do some data manipulation.

I will include my code below. Basically it takes the source html page, cuts the pieces I don't need and convert to JSON object.

Suggestions are always welcome. Thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json
from prettytable import PrettyTable

### First open the file with test data

with open('test_data_bookings.html','r') as f:
        html = f.read()

### Cut off stuff before search string (below could be done more elegant)

output_json = html.split("data =",1)[1]
print(type(output_json))

### Cut off stuf after search string

res = output_json.partition("</script>")[0]
final = res[0:-1]

### Create a function to cut off last line of string

def remove_last_line_from_string(s):
    return s[:s.rfind('\n')]

### Call the function two times (can be done more efficient)
### Optional: uncomment "print statements" to print the result

string = final

string = remove_last_line_from_string(string)
# print('\n\n'+string)

string = remove_last_line_from_string(string)
# print('\n\n'+string)

### Convert STRING to JSON

pretty = json.loads(string)

### Check whether our object is a Dictionary

print(type(pretty))
```